# how to append string to the map of string to interface type

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I have a map of string to interface{} created

```
x := make(map[string]interface{})
```

ultimately i need the following output

```
x["key1"] = ["value1","value2","value3", ......]
```

can anyone help , how to append string values to this map ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only append to slices, not to maps.

To add the value you listed, use:

```
x["key"] = []string{"value1","value2","value3"}
fmt.Println(x)
```

If `"key"` already exists, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to append to it:

```
x["key"] = append(x["key"].([]string), "value4", "value5")
fmt.Println(x)
```

Output (try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-I6vhrK6FmU)):

```
map[key:[value1 value2 value3]]
map[key:[value1 value2 value3 value4 value5]]
```

Note: you have to reassign the new slice (returned by `append()`).

Also note that if `"key"` is not yet in the map or is not of type `[]string`, the above code will panic. To protect against such panic, only append if the value exists and is of type `[]string`:

```
if s, ok := x["key"].([]string); ok {
    x["key"] = append(s, "value4", "value5")
} else {
    // Either missing or not []string
    x["key"] = []string{"value4", "value5"}
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5XUu5T0UpgF).

Comment: panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []string [recovered]
 panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []string

Comment: @AbhishekDK Yes, please read the second half of the answer which explains it and deals with it.